# Loading converted Keras LSTM model in Tensorflow.js leads to tensor shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflowjs-converter

I have defined a LSTM model in Keras and used `tfjs.converters.save_keras_model` to convert it to the Tensorflow.js format. But when trying to load the web-friendly model in JS, it results in an error saying that different shapes were expected than being present in the weights file:

```
BenchmarkDialog.vue:47 Error: Based on the provided shape, [2,128], the tensor should have 256 values but has 139
at m (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at new t (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at Function.t.make (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at ke (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at i (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at Object.kh [as decodeWeights] (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at tf-layers.esm.js:17
at tf-layers.esm.js:17
at Object.next (tf-layers.esm.js:17)
at o (tf-layers.esm.js:17)
```

The model definiton:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
    32,
    batch_input_shape=(30, 5, 3),
    return_sequences=True,
    stateful=True,
    activation='tanh',
))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(LSTM(
    32,
    return_sequences=True,
    stateful=True,
    activation='tanh',
))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(LSTM(
    32,
    return_sequences=False,
    stateful=True,
    activation='tanh',
))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam())
```

The tensor in question belongs to the LSTM layers in model.json:

```
{"name": "lstm_1/kernel", "shape": [2, 128], "dtype": "float32"}
```

Here's the [model.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XXIlU6PYDpUeqc6oUxOxZAgXJY3MP9G-), the [weights file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nlb4_yh8lOZKiWnQyyxMI3BlTLQFhAM6) and the [original keras model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ts8YsbRfYo9yaHYUraEcrKPgke5xkwwo) in case they are helpful.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you please edit the question with the Js code ?